# I have to set up a series of dropdown list input controls, but is there someway to set it up short of manually making a bunch of if statements?

Tags: php, html

I am working on a website which stores maintenance events for different vehicles.  But I need to categorize them by the part, but I am having trouble figuring out how to build the page. They need to select a part, then a location, and sometimes it goes even further. I thought of using Javascript to generate the extra dropdown boxes, but it seems really inefficient to have to make a bunch of if,then statements.  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

EDIT:  My pseudo code is like

```
onChange=>changeFunction()


changeFunction{
if(ddlLocation=brakes){
add select boxes, populate with the individual parts
}else if (...){
}
}
```

Comment: can you share your code ? so people can understand that what's your issue.

Comment: I don't have any actual code at this point.  It is conceptual.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to know more about the specific application to help better, but here is a better way.

Think dynamically, You've got a hundred inputs coming in with unique names, create classes with methods that have method names in a pattern so you can loop through the input names and check for available method based on the method naming convention and call it to handle that type of input specifically.

In that case, if you set it up right, you pass your input all at once to a loop that handles random input as well as it can without if,else.

For example:

```
$carparts = new CarParts();
foreach ($_POST as $name=>$value) {
    $method = strtolower($name) . 'Action';
    if (method_exists($carparts,$method)) {
        $carparts->$method($value);
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the best way to build the form.  I can do a series of if->thens, but that seems like a lot of unnecessary typing.  Is there some kind of method that I could use for this?

Comment: Well, you could loop through an array of elements that you may or may not make by hand and echo them generating a form.

Answer (score 0):

In most situations--but depending on the application--it's better to use a switch statement instead of chained if statements.  Switch statements are also usually faster than multiple if conditions.

> In JavaScript, if statements are generally faster than switch statements when there are just one or two conditions to be evaluated. When there are more than two conditions, and the conditions are simple (not ranges), the switch statement tends to be faster. This is because the amount of time it takes to execute a single condition in a switch statement is often less than it takes to execute a single condition in an if statement, making the switch statement optimal only when there are a larger number of conditions.

[More info about if else vs switch](http://oreilly.com/server-administration/excerpts/even-faster-websites/writing-efficient-javascript.html)

Javascript case statement example:

```
switch(n)
{
 case 1:
   execute code block 1
   break;
 case 2:
   execute code block 2
   break;
 default:
   code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
 }
```